# I'm moving out from SensionExtraBundle but my request argument resolver seems not linked back to the default symfony one

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I'm moving out from SensioExtraBundle as it is abandoned and now throw a lot of deprecation (with Symfony 6.3)
If the documentation is clear how to move the different route/mapEntity and other code usage, It seems that the argument resolver is not working the same way than before.

One of the example is the KNPMenu which don't resolve the object like it did with ExtraBundle

This is a part of one of the definition

```
   extras:
                                context: &action-contacts-context
                                    action: owner.getAction()
```

will complain that owner is not an object : Unable to call method "getAction" of non-object "owner".
If I remember well behind the scene ExtraBundle was adding a extra passage in the
`use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\ExpressionLanguage;`  and do the conversion.

```
       if (!array_key_exists($requestHash, $this->context)) {
            $this->context[$requestHash] = array_map(
                function (string $expression) use ($request) {
                    return $this->language->evaluate($expression, $request->attributes->all());
                },
                $this->navigation->getCurrentItem()->getExtras()['context'] ?? [],
            );
        }
```

How to achieve the same behavior ?

Thanks for your help.